# refresh data when post call is done in angular 4

Tags: angular

I can get and post data from/to the server in angular4 , but for get the posted data i must refresh the page? and i want to know if i can do that without refreshing the page or using :

```
IntervalObservable.create(5000)
   .subscribe(
     () => {
       this.mysqlService.getMysqlData()
         .subscribe(
           res => this.usersMysql = res,
           err => console.log(err.status)
         );
     }
   );
```

service.ts file:

```
// get mysql users Data
public getMysqlData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/BackEndTest/getUsers.php')
        .map( res => res.json());
}
// post data to the server
public addMysqlUserData(fname, lname) {
    const url = 'http://localhost/BackEndTest/postUsers.php';
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(url, {id: '', firstname: fname, lastname: lname}, {headers: headers})
        .map(
            (res: Response) => res.text())
        .subscribe(res => {
           console.log(res.toString());
        });
}
```

post-users-component:

```
export class PostUsersComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private mysqlService: MysqlService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
}
addUser(fname: string, lname: string) {
console.log(fname + ' *** ' + lname);
if (this.mysqlService.addMysqlUserData(fname, lname)){
  alert('Data Inserted Successfully');
   }
 }
}
```

get-users comonent:

```
getUsersMysql() {
this.mysqlServiceC.getMysqlData()
  .subscribe(
    res => this.usersMysql = res,
    err => console.log(err.status)
  );
```

}

thanks for your help

Comment: do you want to get the new data periodically? or on the click of a button?

Comment: I have never tried it, but you may want to look into the rx-polling extension available through the npm package manager: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-polling

Comment: @djangojazz it can be done without plugins, which way is dependant on when the data needs to be updated

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  Why not write an answer then?

Comment: hello, i want the user to see  the inserted data directly after sending them to the server, (my list or my grid show the new data without clicking a button)

Comment: @djangojazz because i dont know when the data needs updating so i cant answer correctly yet

Comment: @HazemHASAN so you want the data updating on the app as soon as it's updated on the server?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yes exactly

Comment: in which case, i would recommend using socket.io so you can update the data on demand

Comment: did you have an example? otherwise i must add a button getdata and click it once i send my data to the server

Comment: just google `socketio` and follow tutorials or chain a `getData` call within the `postData` call's completion event in the subscribe

Comment: did you know how i can do that: call getData within the postData call? i must do that in my service? or import get-user-component in post-user-component?

Comment: 'it can be done without plugins' ... (no answer)'i would recommend using socket.io, go and google it'  LMFAO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem with this solution (i dont know if it's the best), in my service file i added :

```
newDataAdded = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

and in my post-users-component, in addUser method :

```
this.mysqlService.newDataAdded.emit('new data added successfully');
```

and in my get-users-component i subscribed to this event in constructor:

```
this.mysqlService.newDataAdded.subscribe(
  (st: string) => {
    this.getUsersMysql();
  }
);
```

and it works very well

thanks for all your answers